# MySQL - Insert statement is correct, yet it still errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit stumped.

I have a SQL insert statement which is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO region_points (suburb_id, lat, long) VALUES ('1','-33.8737357','150.8697605')
```

I don't see anything at all wrong with the statement, but when i run it, I'm getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'long) VALUES ('1','-33.8737357','150.8697605')' at line 1
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Long is a reserved keyword please use it like `long`

Comment: Don't use reserved words in mysql when naming your fieldnames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LONG` is a mysql reserved word. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.

And identifier quotes are **backticks.**

```
INSERT INTO region_points (suburb_id, lat, `long`) VALUES ('1','-33.8737357','150.8697605')
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

`long` is a reserved keyword,
use like `` `long` `` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try your query like this

```
INSERT INTO region_points (`suburb_id`, `lat`, `long`) VALUES ('1','-33.8737357','150.8697605')
```

It will work.

But it is better to have your field name as "longitude" or something other than "long".

Answer (score 0):

Long is a reserved key word in MySQL. Use it like **'long'**

```
INSERT INTO region_points (`suburb_id`, `lat`, `long`) 
  VALUES ('1','-33.8737357','150.8697605');
```